# Why do we need argument name in typescript function type definition?

Tags: typescript

Imagine we want to define a function that takes a string and returns a number.
Why couldn't we define it as

```
type Foo = string => number
```

but instead we are forced to write

```
type Foo = (arg: string) => number
```

Seems like an overhead

Comment: because javascript parameters are named; plus, adding the parameter name adds to the typesafety and gives context to the end user as to what you expect and why

Comment: Take making a network call with signature `type Ajax = (string, string, string) => Promise<any>` ...can you tell which of these parameters is the url, which is the method, and which is the header string?

Comment: "Why have language designers decided on x" is often hard to answer, because not every motivation is clearly documented. So even if someone like @DerekPollard might make a good guess, there's no guarantee that this is actually correct without a source.

Comment: what would `type A = number | string => number` be? Either `number` or a function that takes string and produces a number? Or is it a function that takes either a number or a string and produces a number?

Comment: @VLAZ the answer is: Yes. /s

Comment: Every time a question like this comes up, it's only answered with speculation. Tuples can be unnamed, and @VLAZ's reason also doesn't hold up for other ambiguous cases that can be made explicit with parenthesis.

Comment: @DerekPollard the answer is `"Yes" | "No"` :P

Comment: @Evert - not sure I follow - with tuples, you have the context of the variable the tuple is coming from; in the case of parameters, there is no context parent variable

Comment: @DerekPollard for your specific case of ajax request parameter name makes sense, but what if I want to define a generic function and the actual parameter name makes no sense since it will depend on concrete use case, e.g `type Morphism<A, B> = (x: A) => B` instead of `A => B`

Comment: @dps interesting; if they're using the same type, shouldn't they have something in common in terms of params signature?

Comment: @DerekPollard You don't have to specify parameter name in many cases if you are programming in point-free style so sometimes javascript parameters are implicit and not named. Also I don't see how adding a parameter name contributes to type safety

Comment: @DerekPollard nope, Morphism type just describes a function that takes 1 argument and returns something, nothing more, no additional context

Comment: Parameter names don't *directly*  improve type safety since they don't affect assignability: e.g., `(x: string)=>void` and `(y: string)=>void` are mutually assignable.  The parameter names are only useful as documentation (which is indirect and not what I'd call "type safety").  The answer "why does TS require the name" is given in the linked question this duplicates.